# How to validate form on submit click with custom reusable hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a custom reusable useForm hook with inputs validation. I want form to be validated on Submit and clear validation when user typing something in the field. Actually the problem with validation. I do not understand how to implement it.

Hook accepts inital state for inputs which is an object with keys and values as empty strings:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": ""
}
```

Hooks also accept a callback function which is actually a submitHandler which fires on submit click but do nothing at the moment.

I have a submit function in useForm hook which expected to fire when a form is valid. To check the form validity I loop through inputs calling validator function on each input. If input is not valid I set an error for that field.

But its not clear what to do next. If I console.log(error) in submit function right after forEach loop after first submit button click its an empty object (on second button click it has errors but not for the first click).

May I ask for help tp deal with problem? How to make this validation work correctly?

**Submit function in useForm hook:**

```
  const submit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Object.entries(input).forEach(([field, value]) => {
      validator(field, value)
    })
    console.log(error) // it's an empty object on first submit button click
    callback();
  };
```

**Validator function:**

```
const validator = (field: keyof Error, value: Input['key']) => {
    switch (field) {
      case 'name':
        if (value.length <= 2) {
          setErrors((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [field]: 'Min 2 characters for name field',
          }));
        }
        break;

      case 'description':
        if (value.length <= 2) {
          setErrors((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [field]: 'Min 2 characters for description field',
          }));
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

**Full hook code:**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

type Input = {
  [key: string]: string;
};

type Error = {
  [key: string]: string | undefined;
};

const useForm = (initValue: Input, callback: () => void) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(initValue);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Error>({});

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    clearValidation(name);

    setInput((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
    setInput({});
  };

  const submit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Object.entries(input).forEach(([field, value]) => {
      validator(field, value);
    });

    callback();
  };

  const validator = (field: keyof Error, value: Input['key']) => {
    switch (field) {
      case 'name':
        if (value.length <= 2) {
          setErrors((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [field]: 'Min 2 characters for name field',
          }));
        }
        break;

      case 'description':
        if (value.length <= 2) {
          setErrors((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [field]: 'Min 2 characters for description field',
          }));
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const clearValidation = (field: keyof Error) => {
    if (field) {
      setErrors((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [field]: undefined,
      }));
      return;
    }
    setErrors({});
  };

  return { input, errors, setInput, handleChange, resetForm, submit };
};

export default useForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `console.log` is empty is because react state setting is asynchronous. It's probably setting it fine, it just happens shortly *after* the  `console.log` because of how React batches state updates and runs them later seamlessly.

I would suggest logging it in the render method or something.

See here for more details: https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The error object is not empty. May I ask what should I do next to make this validation work? Another loop through error object right after the first loop? I need a return is some input invalid or call calckback if all inputs are valid

Comment: You probably need to refactor a little bit. What I would do is change `validator` so that instead of setting the errors, it returns the errors object instead. Then, in the `submit` function you have the object and can do the `setErrors` in there. Since you now have the "raw" errors variable in scope (which doesnt need to wait for react render), you can then branch based on its contents.